# No headphone mic detecting in input devices kali

Tags: kali-linux, microphone

I had some problems with sounds and I fixed the output problems but still can't work with the input. the problem is when I plug in my headphone jack I get the output device for headphone but there is no input for it. only the built-it device. I have no clue what you might need for this so please ask me for information you might need.

Comment: Sometimes this is a problem

Comment: Some headphone jacks are output-only, and a separate jack would be needed for microphone. Others might have both input and output in the same jack, and unfortunately there are two competing standards for these combo jacks: CTIA/AHJ and OMTP. The symptom of using the wrong standard is usually the microphone not working, but a simple adapter that reverses the locations of microphone and ground signals in the plug will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have this problem.  I use `pavucontrol` to solve it (but I haven't figured out how to make the changes persistent between boots).

`pavucontrol` is a GUI which lets you manage pulse audio.  Under "Configuration" you'll see all of your audio devices and the available profiles.

When I look at my headset I see these profiles available:

- Analog Stereo Output + Multi-channel input
- Analog Stereo Output + Mono input
- Analog Stereo Output
- Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Multi-channel input
- Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Mono input
- Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output
- ...

All I do is change the profile to one that has an input and I'll see the microphone and its audio levels appear on the input tab.